# ScriptBundle not including other script depending on the ordering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to combine all scripts into one.. I have two folders, the main folder 'scripts' and the other 'scripts/other'.

When I try:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/all").Include("~/Scripts/*.js", "~/Scripts/other/*.js"));
```

scripts from 'scripts/other' are not included.
but when I invert the order:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/all").Include("~/Scripts/other/*.js", "~/Scripts/*.js"));
```

it works!!
Someone can tell me why?

Comment: Can you send me a repro?

Comment: I'm trying to find this project.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try calling the `IncludeDirectory` methods directly and seeing if you see the same issue?

```
ScriptBundle("~/scripts/all").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/other", "*.js"));
```

If this works, then it's possible we have a bug here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is happening, but this is the code inside the System.Web.Optimization.Bundle:

```
// System.Web.Optimization.Bundle
public Bundle Include(params string[] virtualPaths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < virtualPaths.Length; i++)
    {
        string text = virtualPaths[i];
        Exception ex = Bundle.ValidateVirtualPath(text, "virtualPaths");
        if (ex != null)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        if (text.Contains('*'))
        {
            int num = text.LastIndexOf('/');
            string text2 = text.Substring(0, num);
            if (text2.Contains('*'))
            {
                throw new     ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,     OptimizationResources.InvalidPattern, new object[]
                {
                text
            }), "virtualPaths");
        }
        string text3 = "";
        if (num < text.Length - 1)
        {
            text3 = text.Substring(num + 1);
        }
        PatternType patternType = PatternHelper.GetPatternType(text3);
        ex = PatternHelper.ValidatePattern(patternType, text3, "virtualPaths");
        if (ex != null)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        this.IncludeDirectory(text2, text3);
    }
    else
    {
        this.IncludeFile(text);
    }
}
return this;
}
```